# I think I have a scope issue?

Tags: variables, scope, scheme, let

I'm trying to write a program to calculate Grade Point Average (GPA) that takes a list of grades, and outputs GPA.
(As practice, not homework).

Test case:

```
(GPA? '(A C B B)) 
3.0
```

Here's my best guess:

```
(define a 4.0)
(define b 3.0)
(define c 2.0)
(define d 1.0)
(define f 0.0)


(define (mysum lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst) (accum 0))
    (cond
      [(null? lst) accum]
      [else (loop (cdr lst) (+ accum (car lst)))])))
```

I receive the error:

> "Exception in +: a is not a number"

When I run the test-case:

```
(mysum '(1 2 3 a))
```

it should return 10, but a must not be defined as 4.0 in the procedure.

Can someone give me a simple explanation to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try this instead:

```
(mysum (list 1 2 3 a))
```

It's not a scoping problem, it's just a little misunderstanding regarding quotation. When you write this:

```
'(1 2 3 a)
```

You're saying: I want a list with elements `1, 2, 3, a`. If you *have to* use quotes, the correct syntax for evaluating the `a` variable is:

```
`(1 2 3 ,a)
=> '(1 2 3 4.0)
```

... But in this case is simpler to just use the `list` procedure for building a new list:

```
(list 1 2 3 a)
=> '(1 2 3 4.0)
```

For the record: you can easily add all the elements in a list like this:

```
(apply + (list 1 2 3 a))
=> 10
```

Answer (score 2):

`'(1 2 3 a)` is short for `(quote (1 2 3 a))` and means that the *verbatim* list `(1 2 3 a)` becomes the argument to `mysum`. No attempt to expand variable values under a quote is ever made -- if you write letters there, it's assumed that letters are what you want in your list. In particular the fourth element list is the symbol `a`, not the value of the variable whose name is that symbol.

If you want to interpolate the values of variables you can either use `list` as in the other answer:

```
(mysum (list 1 2 3 a))
```

or a quasiqoute:

```
(mysum `(1 2 3 ,a))
```